# How do I suspend another thread (not the current one)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a simulation of a microcontroller. This simulation is not meant to do a clock cycle precise representation of one specific microcontroller but check the general correctness of the code.

I thought of having a "main thread" executing normal code and a second thread executing ISR code. Whenever an ISR needs to be run, the ISR thread suspends the "main thread".

Of course, I want to have a feature to block interrupts.
I thought of solving this with a mutex that the ISR thread holds whenever it executes ISR code while the main thread holds it as long as "interrupts are blocked".

A POR (power on reset) can then be implemented by not only suspending but killing the main thread (and starting a new one executing the POR function).

The windows API provides the necessary functions.
But it seems to be impossible to do the above with posix threads (on linux).

I don't want to change the actual hardware independent microcontroller code. So inserting anything to check for pending interrupts is not an option.

Receiving interrupts at non well behaved points is desirable, as this also happens on microcontrollers (unless you block interrupts).

Is there a way to suspend another thread on linux? (Debuggers must use that option somehow, I think.)

Please, don't tell me this is a bad idea. I know that is true in most circumstances. But the main code does not use standard libs or lock/mutexes/semaphores.

Comment: Oh dear.  Killing other threads is a very dangerous business, which can permanently screw up any locks or other resources in your program.  Suspending another thread at arbitrary points isn't as bad, but still...

Comment: The main thread code will not use any locks (except the one described which prevents it from being suspended or killed) or allocate dynamic resources.
It does not use standard libraries.

Comment: This was also asked on the glibc mailing list [here](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/libc-help/2010-05/msg00014.html). However, without any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow I think sending the other thread SIGSTOP works.

However, you are far better off writing some thread communication involving senaogires.mutexes and global variables.

You see, if you suspend the other thread in malloc() and you call malloc() -> deadlock.

Did I mention that lots of C standard library functions, let alone other libraries you use, will call malloc() behind your back?

EDIT:

Hmmm, no standard library code. Maybe use setjmp/longjump() from signal handler to simulate the POR and a signal handier to simulate interrupt.

TO THOSE WHO KEEP DOWNVOTING THIS: The answer was accepted for the contents after EDIT, which is a specific scenario that cannot be used in any other scenario.

Comment: Well, in theory there exist re-entrant memory allocators, and your libc might even use one by default.  But yes, OP's request is very hazardous.

Comment: I don't intend to use any standard library. The code to simulate is a complete mini-OS not based on C standard libraries.

Comment: As far as I know on linux (kernel 2.6) it is not possible to send SIGSTOP to a single thread. Instead all threads of a process are stopped. That would not solve my problem.

Comment: Werner Mathe: There doesn't seem to be anything in the kernel code stopping you from using `pthread_kill` to send `SIGSTOP` to an individual thread.

Comment: Unfortunately this will pause the complete process, including the calling thread, if the implementation is POSIX compliant. And as far as I know the implementation in linux is.

Answer (score 15):

SIGSTOP does not work - it always stops the entire process.
Instead you can use some other signals, say SIGUSR1 for suspending and SIGUSR2 for resuming:

```
// at process start call init_pthread_suspending to install the handlers
// to suspend a thread use pthread_kill(thread_id, SUSPEND_SIG)
// to resume a thread use pthread_kill(thread_id, RESUME_SIG)

#include <signal.h>

#define RESUME_SIG SIGUSR2
#define SUSPEND_SIG SIGUSR1

static sigset_t wait_mask;
static __thread int suspended; // per-thread flag

void resume_handler(int sig)
{
    suspended = 0;
}

void suspend_handler(int sig)
{
    if (suspended) return;
    suspended = 1;
    do sigsuspend(&wait_mask); while (suspended);
}

void init_pthread_suspending()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigfillset(&wait_mask);
    sigdelset(&wait_mask, SUSPEND_SIG)
    sigdelset(&wait_mask, RESUME_SIG);

    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = resume_handler;
    sigaction(RESUME_SIG, &sa, NULL);

    sa.sa_handler = suspend_handler;
    sigaction(SUSPEND_SIG, &sa, NULL);
}
```

I am very annoyed by replies like "you should not suspend another thread, that is bad".
Guys why do you assume others are idiots and don't know what they are doing? Imagine that others, too, have heard about deadlocking and still, in full consciousness, want to suspend other threads.
If you don't have a real answer to their question why do you waste your and the readers' time.

An yes, IMO pthreads are very short-sighted api, a disgrace for POSIX.

Comment: I'd like to use this in a C++ context, interrupting a thread by injecting an exception, causing cleanup of RAII objects. I'm trying to port from Windows, where I suspend the problem thread and modify the instruction pointer to the start of an exception throw, before resuming. It works well, and most of the time I can recover after restarting subsystems even if they enter into infinite loops, with minimal manual cleanup of shared state (e.g. resetting mutexes). How do I port that ability to my Linux version? Most articles I see specify to avoid throwing from handlers due to handler stack frame.

Comment: A problem here is that it is not `signal-safe` to use thread local variables from within a signal handler: http://eel.is/c++draft/support.runtime#support.signal-3.2 
Another one is static variables initialization: http://eel.is/c++draft/support.runtime#support.signal-3.7

Answer (score 5):

The Hotspot JAVA VM uses SIGUSR2 to implement suspend/resume for JAVA threads on linux.

A procedure based on on a signal handler for SIGUSR2 might be:

Providing a signal handler for SIGUSR2 allows a thread to request a lock 
(which has already been acquired by the signal sending thread).

This suspends the thread.

As soon as the suspending thread releases the lock, the signal handler can
(and will?) get the lock. The signal handler releases the lock immediately and 
leaves the signal handler.

This resumes the thread.

It will probably be necessary to introduce a control variable to make sure that the main thread is in the signal handler before starting the actual processing of the ISR.
(The details depend on whether the signal handler is called synchronously or asynchronously.)

I don't know, if this is exactly how it is done in the Java VM, but I think the above procedure does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris has the thr_suspend(3C) call that would do what you want.  Is switching to Solaris a possibility?

Other than that, you're probably going to have to do some gymnastics with mutexes and/or semaphores.  The problem is that you'll only suspend when you check the mutex, which will probably be at a well-behaved point.  Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, this might now be desirable.

Comment: I use ubuntu at home. If I have to switch to a different OS, I might as well switch to Windows. But thanks for the hint.

Mutexes and semaphores only influence the current thread. And I don't want to insert instrumentation code for the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to have the main thread execute the ISRs - because that's how the real controller works (presumably).  Just have it check after each emulated instruction if there is both an interrupt pending, and interrupts are currently enabled - if so, emulate a call to the ISR.

The second thread is still used - but it just listens for the conditions which cause an interrupt, and mark the relevant interrupt as pending (for the other thread to later pick up).

Comment: Of course, I thought of having separate "communication threads" but they are not important for the general process.

I don't want any instrumentation in the code that checks for interrupts. I also don't have that on the microcontroller.

I dont want so simulate a specific microcontroller. So there is no such thing as an emulated instruction of the microcontroller.

Comment: By the way, this is no answer to my question.