# Sample program counter of thread

Tags: c++, linux, arm, yocto

I'm currently implementing a watchdog functionality in a multithreaded program where one thread observes the others and checks if they are stuck. If a thread is stuck for a long time, the watchdog thread prints an error.

I would like to add the program counter of the hanging thread to the error message which can be in kernel land. How would I achieve this info from command line or c++?

System is yocto/poky for arm.

Regards

Comment: And what is "program counter" in this context?

Comment: The cpu instruction pointer of the thread.

Comment: have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402160/getting-a-backtrace-of-other-thread (and answers), and have a look to https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/ - can signals be raised to threads in kernel-land?

Comment: Printing just the instruction pointer is rarely useful. Consider the case when it is inside a common function like read(). You need to print the stack trace, ie how the program got to that pointer.

Comment: ‘PTRACE_GETREGS’ will do exactly what you want.  There is also the pid proc directory.

Comment: why would any thread should be stuck in the first place?